# Making the app save data when the app terminates

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I already know how to save things and I can automatically load them when opening the app. But I have no idea how to save them as it closes! I have a button for now. I am trying to save just one value, `StreakNumber`. However, whenever I try, I fail.

When in app delegate I try saying `ViewController.AppSave(ViewController)`. I get an error:

> Editor placeholder in source file
>   Expression resolves to an unused function

and if I use `ViewController.AppSave()`
I get the following error:

> Instance member 'SaveApp' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //TEST PLAY AREA//

    @IBAction func SaveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        SaveApp()
    }

    @IBAction func LoadButton(_ sender: Any) {
        LoadApp()
    }

    ///TEST PLAY AREA ENDS
    public var streakNumber = 0
    public var  streakNumberString = ""

    public var activated = false

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    //Labels
    @IBOutlet var streakNumberLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var remainingTimeTextLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var remainingTimeNumberLabel: UILabel!
    //Buttons
    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Activate()

    }
    @IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Deactivate()
        seconds = 59
        minutes = 59
        hours = 47

    }

    //Timer
    var timer = Timer()
    var seconds = 0
    var minutes = 0
    var hours = 0

    // Nitifications
    //END
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        LoadApp()

        // this enables notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.alert , .sound , .badge], completionHandler:{ didAllow, error in
        })
    }

    func Activate (){
        if activated == false {
            streakNumber += 1

        }
        activated = true
        streakNumberLabel.text = String(streakNumber)
    }

    func Deactivate (){
        if activated == true{
            activated = false
            ActivTimer()

            // Notification
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = " 10  secodns are up "
            content.subtitle = " yep time passed"
            content.body = " The 10 seconds are really up!!"
            content.badge = 1
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 600, repeats:false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content , trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request,withCompletionHandler:nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func Clock(){
        seconds = seconds-1
        if seconds == -1{
            seconds = 59
            minutes = minutes-1
        }
        if minutes  == -1{
            minutes  = 59
            hours = hours-1
        }
        remainingTimeNumberLabel.text = (String(hours) + ":" + String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds))
        if seconds == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 {

            timer.invalidate()

        }
    }

    func ActivTimer(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.Clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }//SAVING STUFF DOESNT WORK
    //

    func SaveApp(){
        streakNumberString = String(streakNumber)
        defaults.set(streakNumberString, forKey: "streakNumbers")
        print("Saved" + String(defaults.integer(forKey: "streakNumbers")))

    }

    func LoadApp(){
        streakNumberString =  defaults.string(forKey: "streakNumbers")!
        print (defaults.integer(forKey: "streakNumbers") )
        streakNumber = Int(streakNumberString)!
        streakNumberLabel.text = String(streakNumber)
    }//
}
```

Comment: appdidEnterBackground & willEnterforeground is the best place. Have a look 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011868/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-when-the-app-is-entering-the-background-for-my-vie 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599431/is-there-any-notification-to-get-before-application-did-enter-background
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039606/refresh-data-after-entering-a-foreground
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648388/ios-app-applicationwillenterforeground-and-it-stucked-for-a-while

Comment: Most of the code you posted has nothing to do with the code causing your errors. Please [edit] your question to include relevant code. Include the actual code you have tried that is causing your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. You can't invoke `SaveApp()` on `ViewController`. You actually need an instance of the `ViewController` to invoke `SaveApp()` on itself.

If you wish your `ViewController` instance to save its data on App termination, you could post a Notification from the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, which is called whenever the app is being minimized and before termination as well:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name("AppAboutToTerminateOrMinimize")))
}
```

Then you could subscribe to that notification in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(AppSave),
                                       name: Notification.Name("AppAboutToTerminateOrMinimize"),
                                       object: nil)
```

Or as rmaddy mentioned in the comments, you can just put the below code in `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` and skip the `AppDelegate` part:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(AppSave),
                                       name: Notification(name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification,
                                       object: nil)
```

This way when the app minimizes/terminates the `AppDelegate` will send notification, the `ViewController` instance (if alive) will receive it and will call `AppSave()`

You'd have to annotate `AppSave()` method as `@objc`

And it's a good practice to use lowerCamelCase for naming of properties and methods /i.e `appSave()` instead of `AppSave()`

Comment: There is a much better way to do this. Simply have the view controller register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` notification. No need for a custom notification. No need to post anything in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` app delegate method.

Comment: @rmaddy how do i do so?

Comment: @Dan i ham still having issues as  i copied your code, changed app save to SaveApp, i still get a notification in the second line Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Could you post your edited `SaveApp()` and `viewDidLoad()` methods?